# Configuration error in django

Tags: django, admin

I am using django with mod_python (I know it is deprecated -- I am just doing this for an exercise), and am getting the following error --

```
"Could not import project.views. Error was: No module named app.models"
```

I am getting the `'No module named app.models"` in several other places as well. My `syncdb` is working fine, and if I go into the `manage.py shell` I can import the models fine. Why is this occurring and what do I need to change? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use absolute imports everywhere. If your project is structured like so:

```
/project/settings.py
/project/app/models.py
/project/app/views.py
```

In `INSTALLED_APPS` you would use `project.app`. In `app` you'd import your models into views: `import project.app.models`, etc. Alternately you can try adjusting your `PYTHONPATH` so your imports work. When you run `./manage.py` you are in your project folder, and Python automatically adds it to the `PYTHONPATH`. This doesn't happen automatically in most deployment scenarios (`mod_python` or other wise).